# how can I move div with position:relative above div with position:absolute?

Tags: html, css, css-position

At my site I have a block with image as background and title above the image:

html

```
<div class="block">
    <img src="someimage.png" />
    <div class="title">Some title</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.block {
    position:relative;
}
.block img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.block .title {
    margin-top:100px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Requirements for the .block:

- I cannot change `<img>` with `<div style='background-image:url(someimage.png)'>` - it must be `<img>`
- `.title` must be relative

But the problem - absolute div hides the title. . Playing with `z-index` do nothing just because `z-index` does not work with relative elements. So my question - how can I organize this block. Any advices will be very apprecated!

Comment: If that `<img>` really is a background image you should add null alt text (i.e. `alt=""`) so that screen readers ignore it. If it has some semantic meaning you should add meaningful alt text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` does work with `relative` positioning. Just set the `.title` to `relative` (or `inherit` since its parent is `relative`) and add a `z-index`

Per http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index

> Only works on positioned elements(position: absolute;, position: relative; or position: fixed;)

CSS

```
.block {
  position:relative;
  width: 100px;
 }

 .block img {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

.block .title {
  margin-top:100px;
  text-align:center;
  color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yy47zukk/)